# Use local custom images as thumbnails for Firefox

Tags: firefox

Is there any way to set custom thumbnail from local storage without having to upload the image and paste its url address? Sometimes images are taking (too much) time to be appeared.

[image: Image. A screenshot of a Firefox dialog box with the title New Shortcut. There are three text entry fields. They are marked Title, URL, and Custom Image URL, respectively]

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a `file:///` path?

Comment: No. I got "Valid URL required" error.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked at this, more than i probably should've, and i have a couple of things to say after encountering the same issue.
The tl,dr is that you can go to the thumbnails folder in:

C:\Users%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXXXXYOURPROFILEXXXXX\thumbnails

And after making sure all thumbnails are generated, select all, go to properties, and mark as read only.

This prevents them being deleted and all is well, unless you add tiles, then you have to do it again to keep the new icon.

That being said, the thumbnail clearing is linked to the setting for clearing history: "Browsing & Downloading history".

Anyone that doesn't want to keep history and has a custom link for a tile thumbnail has this problem.

These thumbnails are supposed to be generated from the actual webpage, so in that sense it makes sense that they are generated on the spot, i guess, although they could be generated and replace the old ones, instead of being all gone when one closes the browser but that's just my opinion.